# Arduino USB Serial communication is throwing error, "avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM3"

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am learning to program Arduino Uno board. To be honest, I am an absolute beginner to it and I just started learning it today. I have finished my first lesson on blinking an LED light. That went well without any issues.

Now, I am trying to send data from my Arduino board to another device through USB serial port communication. For now, I am following this tutorial to get the serial port software working. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/LibraryExamples/SoftwareSerialExample.

So I am trying to compile the following code in the IDE before uploading to the Arduino board.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Native USB only
  }


  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(38400);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

When I compiled it, I am getting the following error.

```
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM3"
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried closing the serial monitor before uploading the code?

Comment: Hi ya. It works when I disconnect and connect the board again. Thanks